# NDK c++ std::thread abort crash on join

Tags: android, c++, multithreading, c++11, android-ndk

First of all, I have no prior C knowledge. I am trying to put together a thread. Here is my example. I call start first, then after doing some work on java side I call stop

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <thread>
std::thread LOOPING_THREAD;
bool do_job = false;

//looping func
 void looping(int test) {
   while (do_job) {
    LOGD("Doing job");
   }
}

//start
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_example_start(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,) {
LOOPING_THREAD = std::thread(looping, 1);
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_example_stop(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
do_job= false;
LOOPING_THREAD.join();
return 0;
  }

  }
```

Above usually works fine but while I cannot reproduce it my self, I get Native crash logs about aborted thread just after calling

```
LOOPING_THREAD = std::thread(looping, 1);
```

for example

```
#00 pc 00044340  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
#01 pc 00041f41  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+32)
#02 pc 0001ba6f  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
#03 pc 00018c11  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
#04 pc 000167d0  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
#05 pc 00010aa3  /data/app/com.app-1/lib/arm/libapp.so    (_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv+230)
#06 pc 0000cfb9  /data/app/com.app-1/lib/arm/libapp.so (_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE+4)
#07 pc 0000d0c1  /data/app/com.app-1/lib/arm/libapp.so (_ZSt9terminatev+8)
#08 pc 00008ddb  /data/app/com.app-1/lib/arm/libapp.so (_ZNSt6threadaSEOS_+38)
```

How can I prevent this crash? I tried to add mutex lock and unlock to function and stop as below but it causes loop to hang for a while before it completes, which is not acceptable in this case.

```
 void looping(int test) {
    while (do_job) {
      mutex.lock()
     LOGD("Doing job");
     mutex.unlock()
  }

 JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
  Java_com_example_stop(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
   mutex.lock()
   do_job= false;
   mutex.unlock()
   return 0;
 }
```

**Update**

I have removed locks, instead, I am detaching the thread with detach() at JNI start(..) just after creating it and letting it run. Then, wait 200 ms at JNI stop(...) after setting do_job = true

Would that work?

Comment: Please fix code indentation in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_ZNSt6threadaSEOS_` is a `std::thread::operator=(std::thread&&)`. You can use `c++filt` utility to demangle symbol names.

From documentation of std::thread::operator=

> If *this still has an associated running thread (i.e. joinable() ==
>   true), call std::terminate(). Otherwise, assigns the state of other to
>   *this and sets other to a default constructed state.

So your global variable `LOOPING_THREAD` contains active thread which has not finished yet.

Comment: Thanks. So, would turning it to  local variable and calling detach() after creating it fix it? Inlining it like    std::thread LOOPING_THREAD = std::thread(looping, 1); LOOPING_THREAD.detach();

Comment: If you call `detach` you will not be able to join the thread. You also loose ability to terminate the thread properly on process shutdown. And detaching thread will not resolve any problems with owning data that the thread uses. So, detaching the thread will solve this particular problem but most probably you will encounter many other problems if you go that way. It is better to refine owning relations in the program and< depending on your needs, not to allow running multiple threads at once.

Comment: Function called in this thread is a very simple while loop that exits after n times running or if a condition is met. I understand once while loop exists thread will exit too, therefore no need for join? Correct?

Comment: No, not correct. You will have problems with program termination, you will have problems with the stop condition (which is still a global variable and will control ALL the threads). And, probably, other problems with object lifetimes.

Comment: I have no C knowledge, is there any sample  I can follow? 

I cannot join the thread after starting it. It has to run and wait for another command  to finish.

Comment: The problem is not with joining thread. Problem is with ownership and lifetime. And these concepts are more or less universal between languages. Who owns the thread? Who controls when it is started and stopped? Who needs to know when it finishes? What data does the thread use? With which objects does it communicate? If you arrange your objects properly, then the problem will be gone. Currently thread does not belong to anybody and everybody uses it. That's the problem.

Comment: Who owns the thread: Android app so, Java vm I guess.
Who needs to know when it finishes: No body. It is fire and forget and end result is not important.
What data does the thread use: No data, it just sends a string to the hardware.
With which objects does it communicate: It does not communicate with any apart from getting the value of global variable to check if it should continue

Comment: I understand that my questions might look rather simple to you. Please ignore if you feel frustrated.

Comment: If this thread sends data to hardware, then you probably do not want two threads to send data at the same time. Will your hardware tolerate such situation?

Comment: I have tried and found no issues with it. Well, there is one but not important and can be safely ignored. I also tried without thread but command doesn't work if it is not sent from a different thread. I have no idea why it doesn't. Unfortunately I don't know the internals of the HAL